# DataGridView loses cell formatting from DataTable.AcceptChanges

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable, formatting, readonly

VB2010. I have researched this issue and cannot seem to find a reason for it or a workaround. What I have is a DataGridView  that is bound to a DataTable. I allow the user to select Edit mode which turns ON/OFF the ReadOnly property. Once ReadMode=True I make sure to set the DataTable to AcceptChanges. When this property is set all my cell formatting disappears.

I do this on form load:

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   dgv.DataSource = Nothing
   dgv.DataSource = GetTripData()
   dgv.AutoResizeColumns()
   dgv.ClearSelection()
   dgv.ReadOnly = True
End Sub
```

Then the user can click on a menu item to go into Edit Mode:

```
Private Sub mnuEditMode_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles mnuEditMode.Click
    If mnuEditMode.Checked Then
        dgv.ReadOnly = False
        dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = True
        dgv.AllowUserToDeleteRows = True
    Else
        dgv.ReadOnly = True
        dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        dgv.AllowUserToDeleteRows = False

        'accept all changes. if we dont do this any row that is deleted will still exist in the DataTable.
        Dim dt As DataTable = CType(dgv.DataSource, DataTable)
        If dt IsNot Nothing Then
            dt.AcceptChanges() 'note: this causes custom cell font to be cleared
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Once in edit mode they can dictate which cells to change. Two cells they put in the list to change are treated a such:

```
'update the proper cells via the DataGridView
dgv.Rows(2).Cells(5).Value = "HOME"
dgv.Rows(2).Cells(6).Value = 10

'bold the cell's font in the DataGridView
Dim styleUpdated As New DataGridViewCellStyle
styleUpdated.Font = New Font(dgv.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
dgv.Rows(2).Cells(6).Style = styleUpdated
dgv.Rows(2).Cells(6).Style = styleUpdated

'refresh the DGV
dgv.Refresh()
```

This works! I can see the changes in the DGV. Now they are done with editing the data so they click on the menu item to set Edit Mode Off and that sets dgv.ReadOnly=True and I also set dt.AcceptChanges. This last method AcceptChanges clears all the bold fonts on modified cells.

Is this expected behavior? If so what suggestions are there to keep my edited cell formatting?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer but I want to post a significant piece of code so I'm posting it as an answer.  I just tested the following code and it worked for me, in that the bold text remained as the two `Buttons` were clicked.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim table As New DataTable

        With table.Columns
            .Add("Id", GetType(Integer))
            .Add("Name", GetType(String))
            .Add("Age", GetType(Integer))
        End With

        With table.Rows
            .Add(1, "Mary", 20)
            .Add(2, "Paul", 30)
            .Add(3, "Peter", 40)
        End With

        DataGridView1.DataSource = table

        Dim style = DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(1).Style

        style.Font = New Font(DataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
        DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(1).Style = style
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        With DataGridView1
            .ReadOnly = True
            .AllowUserToAddRows = False
            .AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        With DataGridView1
            .ReadOnly = False
            .AllowUserToAddRows = True
            .AllowUserToDeleteRows = True
        End With
    End Sub

End Class
```

I'd suggest that you give that code a go and, if it works for you, you know that there's something else going on in your original project.  You can then modify that test project slowly to make it more and more like your existing project and you should then be able to see where this functionality breaks.

Comment: You are right. I stripped the project to the bare minimum and the bold cells do stay. I will audit each procedure to see what causes the oddity.

Comment: After commenting out everything that touched the DGV I found that the DataTable.AcceptChanges method is what actually clears the cell font.

Answer (score 0):

I looked some more and I think the cell formatting clearing is expected behavior. So I came up with a small routine that will save each cell's formatting and then re-apply it after the AcceptChanges. Note that my DataTable is small so you may get a performance hit if you have a large dataset. Please provide any feedback if I have missed something:

```
'updated routine to implement AcceptChanges
'dt.AcceptChanges() 'note: this causes custom cell font to be cleared
 DgvAcceptChanges(dgvMain)

''' <summary>
''' this routine will take a DataGridView and save the style for each cell, then it will take it's DataTable source and accept any
''' changes, then it will re-apply the style font to each DataGridView cell. this is required since DataTable.AcceptChanges will
''' clear any DataGridView cell formatting.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="dgv">DataGridView object</param>
''' <remarks>Could be extended to do other things like cell ReadOnly status or cell BackColor.</remarks>
Public Sub DgvAcceptChanges(dgv As DataGridView)
    Dim dt As DataTable = CType(dgv.DataSource, DataTable)
    If dt IsNot Nothing Then
        'save the DataGridView's cell style font to an array
        Dim cellStyle(dgv.Rows.Count - 1, dgv.Columns.Count - 1) As DataGridViewCellStyle
        For r As Integer = 0 To dgv.Rows.Count - 1
            'the DataGridViewRow.IsNewRow Property = Gets a value indicating whether the row is the row for new records.
            'Remarks: Because the row for new records is in the Rows collection, use the IsNewRow property to determine whether a row
            'is the row for new records or is a populated row. A row stops being the new row when data entry into the row begins.
            If Not dgv.Rows(r).IsNewRow Then
                For c As Integer = 0 To dgv.Columns.Count - 1
                    cellStyle(r, c) = dgv.Rows(r).Cells(c).Style
                Next c
            End If
        Next r

        'this causes custom cell font to be cleared in the DataGridView
        dt.AcceptChanges()

        're-apply the DataGridView's cell style font from an array
        For r As Integer = 0 To dgv.Rows.Count - 1
            If Not dgv.Rows(r).IsNewRow Then
                For c As Integer = 0 To dgv.Columns.Count - 1
                    dgv.Rows(r).Cells(c).Style.Font = cellStyle(r, c).Font
                Next c
            End If
        Next r
    End If
End Sub
```